# AngularJS after reassign directive's received parameter to local variable then view not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Controller">
    <test text="vartext"></test>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
myApp.controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.vartext = ["foo"];
    $timeout(() => $scope.vartext = ["bar"], 3000);
}]);

myApp.directive("test", function() {
   return {
       template: '<div>{{inside[0]}}</div>',
       replace: true,
       scope: {
           text: "="
       },
       controller: ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
            $scope.inside = $scope.text;
       }]
   }
});
```

The behavior is that directive first display "foo". But after 3 seconds it is not changing to "bar".

There are two special cases in this example:

1. After three seconds I changed vartext to a new object. If I use the original object, "bar" will be displayed.
2. In directive's controller I reassigned "text" to a inner variable. If I do not reassign it, even pass a new object "bar" will display.

My question is:

Why after I reassign directive's received parameter to a local variable and then I pass in a new object, the binding to view will be lost? Shouldn't the local variable named `inside` reference to the new object instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment operator only does the assignment once when the $compile service constructs the controller. The assignment operation needs to happen everytime the reference value changes.

---

To avoid the need of doing a new assignment, use `angular.copy` to update the *contents* of the existing reference:

```
myApp.controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.vartext = ["foo"];
    ̶$̶t̶i̶m̶e̶o̶u̶t̶(̶(̶)̶ ̶=̶>̶ ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶v̶a̶r̶t̶e̶x̶t̶ ̶=̶ ̶[̶"̶b̶a̶r̶"̶]̶,̶ ̶3̶0̶0̶0̶)̶;̶
    $timeout(() => angular.copy(["bar"], $scope.vartext), 3000);
}]);
```

That way the *contents* of the new object is copied to the existing reference.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `angular.copy` Function API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

---

Another approach is to use one-way binding and the `$onChanges` life-cycle hook to do a new assignment each times the reference changes:

```
myApp.directive("test", function() {
   return {
       template: '<div>{{inside[0]}}</div>',
       replace: true,
       scope: {
           ̶t̶e̶x̶t̶:̶ ̶"̶=̶"̶
           text: "<"
       },
       controller: ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
            this.$onChanges = function(changes) {
                if (changes.text) {
                    $scope.inside = $scope.text;
                };
            };
       }]
   }
});
```

When the reference assigned to `text` changes, the code assigns the new reference to the `inside` property of `$scope`.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - Life-Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)

Comment: I'm sorry but the question is why the view is not updating when passing new object. You are not answering the question.

Comment: The assignment operator only does the assignment once when the $compile service constructs the controller. The assignment operation needs to happen everytime the reference value changes. See update to the answer.

Comment: Thank you! So basically adding a ng-if to remove and add the directive again would update the view because ng-if recreate the element then reassign the reference in newly created constructor.